# JS/jQuery parentheses error that I can't find

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

Ok, so here's the function I'm working on, and the let line is giving me this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```js
function buildLogRetrieval(jobID, taskID) {
  var div = document.createElement("div")
  var but = $(div).clone(true).css({
    "padding": "5px",
    "background": "black",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "color": "white"
  })

  logButtons = ["log"]
  finishedButtons = []

  for (b in logButtons) {
    lt = logButtons[b]
    console.log(lt)
    t = but.clone(true).text(lt)

    $(t).on('click', function() {
      let l = JSON.parse(await getTaskLogs(jobID, taskID, lt))
      console.log("click")
    })

    finishedButtons.push(t)
  }
  return finishedButtons
}
```

If I comment out the line, the code processes just fine, but I can't seem to figure out what the error is in that line.

Comment: I guess this is another ASI thing. *Always use `;` to end statements!* And use `for..of` instead of `for..in` to iterate over loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) without the `async` keyword ,

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

```
$(t).on('click', async function() {
    let l = JSON.parse(await getTaskLogs(jobID, taskID, lt))
    console.log("click")
})
```

Comment: Yup, you all got it dead on... I was missing the async in the function call in the on the click function... It never even occurred to me that it needed to be there.  I hope you all consider this a blanket thank you, as you all got it so right so fast while I was on a work call. 

THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `await` without an async context. Try this:

```
function buildLogRetrieval(jobID, taskID) {
    var div = document.createElement("div")
    var but = $(div).clone(true).css({"padding":"5px", "background":"black", "border-radius":"5px", "color":"white"})

    logButtons = ["log"]
    finishedButtons = []

    for(b in logButtons) {
        lt = logButtons[b]
        console.log(lt)
        t = but.clone(true).text(lt)

        $(t).on('click', async function() {
            let l = JSON.parse(await getTaskLogs(jobID, taskID, lt))
            console.log("click")
        })

        finishedButtons.push(t)
    }
    return finishedButtons
}
```

For further explanaiton please read [this](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your env supports async/await, your click handler needs to be async to use await.

Change

```
$(t).on('click', function() {
```

To

```
$(t).on('click', async function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is exactly in  `await getTaskLogs` and to solve it your code should be something like this:

```
$(t).on('click', async function() {
    let l = JSON.parse(await getTaskLogs(jobID, taskID, lt))
    console.log("click")
})
```

You can only have `await` inside `async` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the line that's causing the error?

```
let l = JSON.parse(await getTaskLogs(jobID, taskID, lt))
```

If so, then there are two possible problems:

1) You're running in an environment that does not support async/await yet (it's a quite new feature to javascript)
2) Or it's complaining that you've used await in a non-async function